# MySQL SELECT 1 AS sort_col: is there is a column for 1?

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, alias

From Mysql [Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html) :

> To cause rows in a UNION result to consist of the sets of rows
>   retrieved by each SELECT one after the other, select an additional
>   column in each SELECT to use as a sort column and add an ORDER BY
>   following the last SELECT:
>
> ```
> (SELECT 1 AS sort_col, col1a, col1b, ... FROM t1)
> UNION
> (SELECT 2, col2a, col2b, ... FROM t2) ORDER BY sort_col;
> ```
>
> To additionally maintain sort order within individual SELECT results,
>   add a secondary column to the ORDER BY clause:
>
> ```
> (SELECT 1 AS sort_col, col1a, col1b, ... FROM t1)
> UNION
> (SELECT 2, col2a, col2b, ... FROM t2) ORDER BY sort_col, col1a;
> ```
>
> Use of an additional column also enables you to determine which SELECT
>   each row comes from. Extra columns can provide other identifying
>   information as well, such as a string that indicates a table name.

My Question:

Do I need to create two additional columns in the table for this purpose?

Comment: No you dont need additional columns in the table (just need those in the query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The `sort_col` of the mysql manual is created on the fly with constant values (1, and 2).

Analogically, you can SELECT any value you wish with no need of any table:

`SELECT 1, 2, 3 FROM dual;`